# I want to implement pause and resume feature in my downloader in c# how can I do that?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am developing a Download Manager in that I want to add pause and resume feature how can I do that? I am using webclient, I was trying to use CancelAsync Method but it is not working. So how I can do that? I am providing my code.

```
public void download(string link, string path)
    {
        uri = new Uri(link);
        String FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, path +@"\" + FileName);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += downloadprogress;
    }
```

How can I implement Pause and resume feature?

Comment: That assumes your server *has* the functionality to pause a request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpWebRequest or WebRequest - Resume Download ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336203/httpwebrequest-or-webrequest-resume-download-asp-net)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995705/adding-pause-and-continue-ability-in-my-downloader